# Inverse gamma sum convergence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I have been working on the following problem:

Assume $X_k$ is a random variable that follows a $\Gamma(3,k)$ distribution. Then

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{X_i}-\frac{1}{2} \log n\overset{p}{\to}0$$

Well, I know that the random variable $Y_k=\frac{1}{X_k}$ follows an inverse gamma distribution,and clearly $-\frac{1}{2}\log (n)=\log(n^{-1/2})$ so I am guessing  $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{X_i}$ can be written in terms of logarithm in some way....

I am wondering if anyone has any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This does not converge to 0 in probability, it converges to $\gamma/2$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. To see this, note that the expectation of $X_i$ is $1/2i$ for each $i$, and that convergence in expectation implies convergence in probability. We have
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{X_i} - \frac{1}{2}\log(n)\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{X_i} - \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{2i} + \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{2i} - \frac{1}{2}\log(n)\right] = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{i} - \log(n)\right) \to \frac{\gamma}{2}. $$
The last convergence is the definition of the Euler-Mascheroni constant. From this we get that
$$ \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{X_i} - \frac{1}{2}\log(n) \to \frac{\gamma}{2} \text{ in }\mathbb{P}. $$